# HTML5 INPUT type='number' - distinguish between focus and value-change mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, html, input, click

In the HTML5 `INPUT type='number'` the user can change the value by clicking on up/down arrows that are part of the INPUT box. The user might also click in the box for focus or for editing its contents.

Is there any easy way to distinguish between these two activities in the `click` trigger?

---

from @cvsguimaraes answer, which better demonstrates the theory.

using his methodology, here is my finished(?) version. the purpose: make sure regular `change` triggers are called when using +/- to change data.

```
// input/mouseup triggers to call change from +/- mouse clicks
// want to wait 500ms before calling change in case successive clicks
render.inputCh = false;
render.inputCt = 0;
render.inputFn  = function(e) {
    render.inputCh = true;
}
render.mouseupFn  = function(e) {
    if( render.inputCh ) {
        render.inputCh = false;
        render.inputCt++;
        setTimeout( next, 500 );
    }       
    function next() {
        render.inputCt--;
        if( render.inputCt ) return;
        var change = document.createEvent("Event");
        change.initEvent('change',true,true);
        e.target.dispatchEvent(change);
    }
}

// using input/mouseup triggers
document.getElementById('number').addListener('input',render.inputFn,true);
document.getElementById('number').addListener('mouseup',render.mouseuptFn,true);

// normal change trigger - will be called normally and via +/- mouse click
document.getElementById('number').addListener('change',changeFn,false);
```

on chrome it's working flawlessly so far *except* that when you remove focus from the ITEM the `change` trigger will kick in again.  I solved this by having a low level change trigger that stops propagation if the previous change call was from the `mouseup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user change the value by clicking on up/down arrows the `input` event is triggered conveniently between `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('age')
const on = (ev, fn) => input.addEventListener(ev, fn)

const status = document.getElementById('status')
const write = (...txt) => status.innerText = txt.join()

let lastEv = 'none';
on('keydown', () => lastEv = 'keydown')
on('mousedown', () => lastEv = 'mousedown')

on('input', () => {
  if (lastEv === 'mousedown') write('changed from mouse', input.value);
  if (lastEv === 'keydown') write('changed from keyboard', input.value)
});
```

```html
<input id="age" type="number" value=30> <br>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: arent mouse{down,up} the press and release events, rather than the click top/bottom ones?

Comment: I won't answer, because I didnt' know it from myself; but this seems like a real convoluted way to say "don't use click, use input instead".

Comment: @FallingBullets yah, but pluss the oninput event

Comment: @Joeri - the problem I had with `input` is a user taking more than 500ms to edit the field.  thought click would have less ambiguity in data-entry

Comment: @cvsguimaraes - is there any guarantee `input` will fire before `mouseup` - I have been snakebit when the natural order of events is not as reported by the browser.

Comment: @cc young Yep, I tested it from myself in webkit

Comment: think you nailed it!  based on your work, put my solution at bottom of question.  thanks!

Comment: This doesn't quite work on all cases--if you click an arrow button with the mouse, then press Backspace, it thinks the Backspace was a mouse event. Chrome 103.0.5060.114 and FF 102.0.1

Comment: Using `keydown` rather than `keypress` seems to work though. Keypress is deprecated anyway. I'll add an edit but feel free to rollback for any reason.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/K6nHa/2/) is a demo of how you can capture and analyze which events change the input and in what order.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('number'),
    events = [
        "click",
        "mousedown",
        "mouseup",
        "focus",
        "change",
        "input",
        "keydown",
        "keypress",
        "keyup"
    ];
events.forEach(function(ev) {
    input.addEventListener(ev, function() {
        console.log(ev, ' => ', input.value);
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" />
```

Comment: This is interesting, but how does this tell you unambiguously whether the user clicked an arrow or typed the number when it changes?